# Please do not edit Swiss Guillemets

Tags: discussion

Today a user made a post edit where only the Guillemets in the title where changed from:

> Wann wird «das Morgen» statt «der Morgen» benutzt?

to

> Wann wird »das Morgen« statt »der Morgen« benutzt?

Not that I want to be too picky, but these [German guillemets are not allowed in Switzerland](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1858/double-quotes-in-switzerland-for-german-texts-guillemets-g%C3%A4nsef%C3%BCsschen).

As it does not improve the post in any way and to show our respect for typographic rules of other German-speaking countries we should not perform such a minor post edit.

Also see [What's the value of edits which replace quotation characters and apostrophes?](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1066/whats-the-value-of-edits-which-replace-quotation-characters-and-apostrophes)

Comment: Note that the article you refer to does it inconsistently.
It uses Swiss style guillemets in the heading, but
German style guillemets in the body. (Admitted, the latter
occur in a quotation.)

Comment: @Uwe: yeah - that is a quote from a German magazine, they are not expected to use Swiss Guillemets.